# Extending a representation of a $C^*$-algebra to its unitization

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, representation-of-algebras

I have a basic question about representations of non-unital $C^*$-algebras.

Let $A$ be a non-unital $C^*$-algebra, and $\rho\colon A\to\mathcal{B}(H)$ a $*$-representation of $A$ on some separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$.

Suppose that $\rho$ satisfies the following two properties:

1. It is non-degenerate, i.e. $\rho(A)\cdot H$ is dense in $H$;
2. For any $a\neq 0$ in $A$, $\rho(a)$ is not a compact operator on $H$.

**Question:** Can we extend $\rho$ to a representation of its unitization $A^+$ on $\mathcal{B}(H)$, for the same space $H$?

*Thoughts:* Clearly if $\rho(A)$ doesn't contain $1_{\mathcal{B}(H)}$ then it is possible to extend $\rho$ in this way. But it's not clear to me that $1_{\mathcal{B}(H)}$ can't be in the image of $\rho$. (I'm not sure if conditions 1 and 2 are required, but I've included them just in case they help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take
$$\overline{\rho}: A^+\to B(H): (a,\lambda)\mapsto \rho(a)+\lambda 1_H.$$
No assumptions are required.

Comment: Ah indeed, thanks.